# Find derivative of $\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{x+1}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I should find the derivative of $$ \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{x+1}} $$
I know how to deal with general derivatives (patterns for fractions or composition) but I don't know (and it wasn't on my exercises) how to deal with derivative of for example
$$ (x+1)^{1/3} $$
I saw on that forum that in some cases people use inequalities but I think that there is a more general approach...

Comment: The derivative of $(x+1)^{1/3}$ is $\frac13(x+1)^{-2/3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical case for using the *logarithmic derivative*. Denoting this function as $f(x)$, we have:
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac13\Bigl(2\cdot\frac 1x-\frac1{x+1}\Bigr)=\frac 13\frac{x+2}{x(x+1)}, $$

and therefore
$$f'(x)=\frac 13\frac{x+2}{x(x+1)}\biggl(\frac{x^2}{x+1}\biggr)^{\mkern-6mu\frac 13} = \frac{x+2}{3(x+1)\sqrt[3]{x(x+1)}} $$

Answer (score 2):

Write the whole thing exponentially and then use the derivative of a product + chain rule:

$$\left(\sqrt[3]\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right)'=\left(x^{2/3}(x+1)^{-1/3}\right)'=\frac23x^{-1/3}(x+1)^{-1/3}+\left(-\frac13\right)(x+1)^{-4/3}x^{2/3}=$$

$$=\frac13\left(\frac2{\sqrt[3]{x(x+1)}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^4}}\right)=...etc.$$

The etc. above means you can write many equivalent expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Overkill? Implicit differentiation:

$y^3=\frac{x^2}{x+1}.$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:

$3y^2(dy/dx)= \dfrac{2x(x+1)- x^2}{(x+1)^2};$

$3y^2(dy/dx)=\dfrac{x^2+2x}{(x+1)^2};$

$y \not =0:$

$dy/dx=\dfrac{1}{3y^2}\dfrac{x(x+2)}{(x+1)^2};$

Left to do : Epress $y^2$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use the quotient rule and the chain rule